# Problems in generating random numbers

Tags: c

I'm using the following code for generate the random numbers in C programming, but for every compilation a particular set of random numbers are generating repeatedly. Can anybody mention the correction here???

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{   
  int i,a[40];

  for(i=0;i<40;i++)
  {    
    a[i] = rand() % 6;
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
  } 
  getch();
}
```

Comment: You've used the wrong tag.  This isn't a C# question.

Comment: You aren't initializing the random seed correctly. There are multiple correct answers below which address this.

Comment: This question is asked repeatedly; please show some effort and do a search before asking the question. You will get your answer faster that way and not waste anyone's time. It's a win for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize random seed to a different value, please see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yeah, but I am kinda lazy, please downvote so that the other answer gets on top :)

Answer (score 2):

[Per the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html),

> If `rand()` is called before any calls to `srand()` are made, **the same sequence shall
>   be generated as when `srand()` is first called with a seed value of 1.** [emph. mine]

You need to mix it up, something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <time.h> 

main()
{   
  int i,a[40];

  // seed the PRNG with some random value
  // the current time is often used. You might want to incorporate
  // other sources of entropy as well.
  srand(time(NULL)); 

  for( i = 0 ; i < 40 ; i++ )
  {    
    a[i] = rand() % 6;
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
  } 
  getch();
}
```

One should note that

- seed the PRNG just once at beginning of execution
- The reason for incorporating more sources of entity, rather than just relying on the current system clock is that the system clock itself is not very random -- to invocations quite close to each other my result in similar sequences. Other good sources of entropy include:

  - hard disk statistics
  - network I/O
  - process activity
  - keystroke latency
  - mouse movements
  - etc.

Although looking at user interface components such as keystrokes and mouse movements won't buy you much in the way of entropy if your software is running, say, on a server, where the keyboard and mouse are likely to be idle for long periods of time.

Comment: Your's should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this (inserted line) to seed the random number generator:

```
  //...
  int i,a[40];
  srand(clock());  //inserted line
  for(i=0;i<40;i++)
  //...
```

The `clock()` function will provide a different *seed* value each *clock tick*, resulting in a new and different initialization to the `rand()` function.